# Get single row from multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

Just scratching head for a few days for a simple but not possible by me :(. I have table like this

```
Server |  Domain | Department |UniqueID
--------------------------------------
A      |   abc   | HR         | 123
A      |   abc   | Acc        | 123
A      |   abc   | Other      | 123
B      |   efg   | HR         | 456
C      |   efg   | Acc        | 789
```

I want output like this

```
Server |  Domain | Department |UniqueID
----------------------------------------
A      |   abc   | All Dept   | 123
B      |   efg   | HR         | 456
C      |   efg   | Acc        | 789
```

So if there are multiple Dept, it is All Dept.
Please advise

Comment: Why would you want "all dept" if there are duplicates?  What if there are only two departments?

Comment: I am just trying to get query where at least I can put something. I was not aware using MIN can do the trick

Answer (score 2):

you can group by `Server ,Domain,UniqueID` then use `if count > 1 then All Dept`

```
select 
  Server ,Domain,case when count(1) > 1 then 'All Dept' else min(Department) end as Department,UniqueID
from T
group by Server ,Domain,UniqueID
```

Comment: [Online Demo Link | db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=05e9ac127fc67c6c200127488ebf737f)

Comment: Simple but on the spot solution. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `GROUP BY` and aggregate function `COUNT()` to achieve the result.

```sql
SELECT 
  Server, 
  Domain, 
  CASE WHEN Count(UniqueID) > 1 THEN 'All Dept' ELSE MIN(Department) END as 'Department', 
  UniqueID
    FROM Dept
GROUP BY Server, Domain, UniqueID
```

**Update:**

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/24f56/2

Comment: in sql server it'll get error : `Column 'T.Department' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`, [SQL Server 2012 | db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=d40b8c8477b4d223ae7ffa3f967da8b1)

Comment: Thanks @Wei, I fixed it for MSSQL, I created the query for MySql earlier.

Comment: It's simple but doesn't know why I could not think of it. Thanks a lot for the solution and for sqlfiddle as I didn't know it exists.

Comment: You're welcome. Please upvote and Mark it as answer if it has helped.

Answer (score 0):

My general approach is like this:

```
select server, domain, uniqueid,
       (case when min(department) = max(department)
             then min(department)
             else 'Multiple'
        end) as department
from t
group by server, domain, uniqueid;
```